# Can you create a 'view of a view' in Couchbase Lite?

Tags: ios, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-view

I'd like to optimise a Couchbase Lite query on iOS in two steps:

1. create a view+index which sums only the necessary fields required.
2. make a pair of similar views that are aggregate sums based on the first view.

Is this possible to do? Eg to make a 'view of a view'?

Comment: is this a homework question?  Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the answer is no, from my reading of the couchbase lite docs.

Comment: Thanks @PhilWilson hahaha!